# QML TextInput ignoring inputMethodHints

Tags: qt, qml

I'm creating a custom text input in QML. One of its configuration is that it's a field that should only accept digits I did it like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Item {

    property string vmFont: "Mono"
    property string vmPlaceHolder: "Some text ..."
    property bool vmNumbersOnly: false

    // Qt Quick approach to make internal variables.
    Item {
        id: own
        property string enteredText: ""
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: lineEditRect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#e4f1fd"
        radius: 2
    }

    TextInput {
        id: lineEdit
        text: vmPlaceHolder
        color: "#5499d5"
        font.family: vmFont
        font.pixelSize: 13
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        //inputMethodHints: vmNumbersOnly ? Qt.ImhDigitsOnly : Qt.ImhNone
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
        verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
        leftPadding: 10
        width: lineEditRect.width
        height: lineEditRect.height
        onActiveFocusChanged: {
            if (activeFocus){
                if (own.enteredText === ""){
                    // Removing the placeholder
                    lineEdit.text = "";
                }
            }
        }

        onEditingFinished: {
            own.enteredText = lineEdit.text;
            if (lineEdit.text === ""){
                lineEdit.text = vmPlaceHolder
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, even though that the inputMethodHits is set to Qt.ImhDigitsOnly, the text input still accepts all kinds of keypresses. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think that `inputMethodHints` is for virtual keyboards (e.g. mobile phone software keyboards, Qt Virtual Keyboard, etc.). For restricting input when a physical keyboard is in use (though it can also be used when a virtual keyboard is in use), you can use [`inputMask`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#inputMask-prop) and [`validator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#validator-prop). For example, the following code would allow only four digits from 0 to 9 to be entered:

```
TextInput {
    inputMask: "9999"
}
```

Think of `inputMethodHints` as affecting what the virtual keyboard displays and how it behaves, and these properties as affecting what the `TextInput` itself allows as input.

Comment: I tried to using input mask but it did not let me enter ANY text. So I just gave up and attempted to parse the int in the onFinishedEdited event as I already had code for that condition. Thanks anywas

Comment: Have you tried using a [validator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#validator-prop)? ex: `validator: IntValidator{}`

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me in any device:

```
TextInput {
    validator: RegExpValidator{regExp: /[0-9]+/}
}
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This will work on positive integers. I won't accept decimals or genative numbers